# php 301 redirect to all t

Tags: php, http, redirect

According to: [Daily Blog Tips](http://www.dailyblogtips.com/how-to-setup-a-301-redirect/)

The code below does two things:

1) It will add (or remove) the www. prefixes to all the pages inside your domain.

2) The code below redirects the visitors of the http://domain.com version to http://www.domain.com.

**My question:** Is inserting the code below in the index.php page sufficient to create a 301 redirect that will work on all pages of the website I am working on?

```
<?php
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],0,3) != 'www') {
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>
```

Comment: No. You should do this via `.htaccess`

Comment: Don't brew up something you don't understand. Use Apache's mod_rewrite which is made for this.

Comment: Why won't the code above work for a redirect?

Comment: @MHZ it will work for index.php, but not the others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > My question: Is inserting the code below in the index.php page sufficient to create a 301 redirect that will work on all pages of the website I am working on?

No. That will only work for `http://www.example.com/index.php` and not for `http://www.example.com/whatever/whatever/file.php`. You're better off using [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to accomplish this task. You could stick this in your document root `/.htaccess` file.

```
# Rewrite "example.com -> www.example.com".
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Code was taken from [HTML5 Boilerplate's .htaccess](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with apache mod_rewrite... where am I suppose to insert this code? i appreciate the answer ;)

Comment: @MHZ create a `.htaccess` file in your web document root

Comment: @MHZ for a mod_rewrite tutorial, see the one at [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/). As to why what you have doesn't work, it is only executed when index.php is accessed: no other files activate the code as it is in index.php only.

Comment: The reason it will only work for index.php is because that's the only file you mentioned putting it in. Now, it's possible that your site already uses mod_rewrite to call index.php for every page. If that's the case, then this would indeed work. mod_rewrite is a much better tool for the task though. As an example, it's highly doubtful that your webserver calls index.php when a browsers requests an image file.